# VueJS hot reload slow

Tags: performance, vuejs2, hot-reload

I have a vuejs application with .vue files. In one of them I have a template with like 600 lines of HTML.

The problem is, when I modify this .vue file it took 30 seconds to recompile every time with the hot reload.

1/ Maybe I am doing something wrong?

2/ There is a way to improve this?

3/ Is there an alternative?

I use the base skeleton of vue JavaScript, to initiate:

```
vue init webpack project_name
```

To run:

```
yarn run dev
```

Comment: There is not way to debug this, you have to see what webpack is doing in the terminal when loading your app. This is most likely a problem can only be solved by you

Comment: What tools i could use to add verbose and debug on webpack hot reload?

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions on this Medium article to optimize your build:

https://medium.com/ottofellercom/0-100-in-two-seconds-speed-up-webpack-465de691ed4a

About me i apply HardSourcePlugin and i divide by 2 the time of build.

Comment: hi, im stuck at the same thing. how did you apply this plugin ? we need to replace

Comment: Hi, very old thing i don't rememember exactly but you can follow the manual : https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin

Comment: oh ok, do I need to replace `vite` then ?